# Casting Textbox KeyEventArgs

Tags: c#, winforms, events, casting, keyevent

I am trying to get KeyUp events for textBox control at runtime but I am struggling to cast correctly.  The code below compiles and I can see the event info when I add a Watch/Inspect rtbPrivateNote_KeyUp -> EventArgs e:

```
public class Form1
{
    private System.Windows.Controls.TextBox rtbPrivateNote = null;
    
    public InitFormControls()
    {
        LoadSpellChecker(ref pnlPrivateNotes, ref rtbPrivateNote, "txtPrivateNotePanel");
        rtbPrivateNote.TextChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventHandler(rtbPrivateNote_TextChanged);
        rtbPrivateNote.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(rtbPrivateNote_KeyUp);
    }
    
    private void LoadSpellChecker(ref Panel panelRichText, ref System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txtWithSpell, string ControlName)
    {
        txtWithSpell = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
        {
            Name = ControlName
        };
        txtWithSpell.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        txtWithSpell.Width = panelRichText.Width;
        txtWithSpell.Height = panelRichText.Height;
        txtWithSpell.AcceptsReturn = true;
        txtWithSpell.AcceptsTab = true;
        txtWithSpell.AllowDrop = true;
        txtWithSpell.IsReadOnly = false;
        txtWithSpell.TextWrapping = System.Windows.TextWrapping.Wrap;
    
        ElementHost elementHost = new ElementHost
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Child = txtWithSpell
        };
    
        panelRichText.Controls.Add(elementHost);
    }
    
    // private void rtbPrivateNote_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  // WONT COMPILE
    private void rtbPrivateNote_KeyUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (e.Key == Key.Enter  
        //    || e.Key == Key.Return)
        //{
        //    Do Something here
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing WinForms and WPF controls/code. The event you are subscribing has [WPF KeyEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyeventargs?view=netcore-3.1) rather than  the default for WinForms [KeyEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Why are you passing `panelRichText` by `ref`?

Comment: @flydog I'm using the panel to hold the text control at runtime.

Comment: @IvanStoev no WPF controls are used - I think you saw the control name "WPFControlName" which I copied from some previous code I use - I renamed it now but its just the assigned control name

Comment: I see that you are using the `panelRichText` control in the function, but you aren't changing the value of the parameter.  You don't need to pass it by ref.

Comment: The name doesn't matter. `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`, `System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventHandler`, basically everything from `System.Windows.Controls` is NOT WinForms. Also the need of `ElementHost`. All WinForms components are from `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. You could have easily seen that if you clicked the 2 links from my previous comment. For some reason your code is hosting WPF TextBox control inside WinForms form/control, hence the clash between 2 classes with the same name, but different namespaces. The accepted "answer" won't help, you'll just find it the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't cast it like that because KeyEventArgs derives from EventArgs and since e is not a KeyEventArgs, it says that it can't cast it.

If e was of type KeyEventArgs then you could cast it to EventArgs.

```
private void rtbPrivateNote_KeyUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KeyEventArgs ke = e as KeyEventArgs;
    if (ke != null)
    {
       if (ke.Key == Key.Enter  || ke.Key == Key.Return)
       {
        //Do Something here
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this a touch by saying `if (e is KeyEventArgs ke)` and getting rid of the previous line (that does the cast)

Comment: This makes no sense. Read again my comment under the question. You are trying to cast to a wrong type. Be sure that if `private void rtbPrivateNote_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` won't compile, then the above `if` will never be entered. All you need is to use the correct KeyEventArgs type in the event handler signature.